# Using cufon with CSS generated content via (:before/:after)

Tags: css, cufon

I'm trying to add a '/' character to decorate an "h1" with the following CSS:

```
.h1:after {
    content: "/";
    color: #FFC502;
    font-family: 'Neo Sans Pro Medium',verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I'm also using CUFON font replacement for all "h1" using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cufon();
});

function cufon() {
    Cufon.replace('h1:not(.noCufon)');
    Cufon.replace('h2');
    Cufon.now();
}
```

The h1 is correctly replaced with the neo sans font by cufon, but the generated content isn't. The last '/' will render in Verdana no matter what I do. Is there a way to make cufon to recognize and replace the CSS generated content?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the W3C standard requires `::after` and `::before`. There was some ambiguity, however, and every major browser supports `:after` and `:before` -- and IE *doesn't* support `::after` and `::before`. So you shouldn't actually change anything, but I think it's worth knowing.

Comment: @KRyan: The standard does not require double colons for `::after` and `::before`, it only requires them for new pseudo-elements going forward and recommends them for existing ones while still allowing single colons for backward compatibility. IE does support `::after` and `::before` starting from version 9, though, so if one isn't concerned with IE8, one *should* start using double colons.

Comment: Teaches me to base my knowledge on a blog post rather than check the standard itself. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a JavaScript library, Cufón doesn't support CSS generated content, because it is not accessible through the DOM. There is no way to make it recognize and perform font replacement on generated content.

Comment: css can be inserted into HTML using the `style` Attribute (I don't like this personally I would rather use an external stylesheet) but you could change the Style using Javascript by changing that attribute

Comment: I was hoping that some trick could be used to recognized the CSS generated content, but since I was aware that it didn't change the DOM I was not much hopeful... I'll inject the '/' character via JavaScript with the proper CSS selectors and update the question with the workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hate cufon many developers are moving to google webfonts as it is much easier to manage and does not contain as many bugs as the cufon system.

http://www.google.com/webfonts

for example you just include the font like so

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Skranji' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
body{ font-family: 'Skranji',verdana,arial,sans-serif }
```

Of course you would have to look for your desired font.

Comment: I don't like cufon either. I don't use it for my own projects. But I have to use it when the customer requires it. The font is already set to neo sans. I'll inject the '/' character via JavaScript.